There is an avaliable sewage network from a city using osmnx.graph_from_place?
I would like to have access to the sewage network of a city in the world, knowing the elevations, locations of the sewers and the pipelines that connect them.
The idea of ​​this is to use it in an academic project to optimize the location of water quality monitoring points. The network would be used to create a graph and apply the optimization method.
I tried to get this information using the osmnx.graph_from_place option, but I couldn't identify which city does present this information. I found that the maps are obtained from OpenStreetMap but I can't find a list with the information that is available.
red_ciudad = ox.graph_from_place(ciudad, network_type='all')
Currently, I have already tried using a shp file from Mexico City, but the momepy library in python is not capable of adequately reproducing the connections between the sewers.
graph = momepy.gdf_to_nx(cdmx_canal, approach='primal')
This is the result:


OSMnx can model any networked infrastructure on OpenStreetMap. So the question is really: do these data exist on OpenStreetMap? You can just search/explore CDMX on OSM to see if the sewer data are there.

Thank you for your answer. But I would also like to know if anyone has successfully uploaded the sewage network of any city in the world, not necessarily Mexico City, using the OSMnx library.

What do you mean by "uploaded?" OSMnx has no upload capabilities.

Technically, some sewers are mapped. Practically, I don't think the data is complete enough for your purpose.
As a rule of thumb, if you want to know how accurately OSM maps a feature, ask yourself three questions:

Would a random person know where this feature is?
Would a random person care about this feature?
If the map is wrong, or missing a feature, how likely would someone be to notice?

If you think about something like roads, anyone can see where a road is. Everyone needs to know where the roads are to get where they're going. It's obvious when a road is missing.
In contrast, sewer locations might only be known by whoever built it. Most people can ignore their sewers, and won't notice if a map doesn't list them. It's invisible infrastructure.
Some of this is mapped. I searched the OSM wiki, and found the following tag combinations:

utility=sewerage
substance=sewage

For example, here's a map of substance=sewage in London. (View in Turbo.)

This is one of the cities where this is relatively well-mapped. However, most of the sewers are still missing. For example, it shows no sewers in Camden Town, and according to my friend who lives in Birmingham, Camden Town does have sewage service.
If you'd like to explore this on your own, you can use Overpass Turbo to search for specific tags. Once you know the tag you're interested in, you can use any osmnx function that accepts a tags argument to filter for that tag. For example, you could use a tags dict like {'utility': 'sewerage'}.
You would need to convert this into a graph. Assuming that OSM had this data, you'd have the problem that osmnx.graph_from_place() doesn't accept tags. I believe you could work around this by using the custom_filter argument, and that would accomplish something very similar. However, I have not personally used this feature.
